# How Create Function with Array Arguments PHP

Tags: php

Simple question...

wanna create something like this:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'posts',
  'limit' => 5,
  'cat' => 'news'
);
```

Then, a function that can actually get these 'keys'... like:

```
function get_posts($args) {

    $post_type = $args['post_type'];
    $limit = $args['limit'];
    $cat = $args['cat'];

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posttype='$post_type'  .... ");

    // other code...
}
```

how can i?

Sorry for bad english and thanks in advance.

Comment: Haven't just perfectly answered your question with your example?

Comment: i can't get this working in that way... :(

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: Then show more code that doesn't work. You are not calling the function, so it's hard to advise on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

However, it seems that you have already answered yourself!

You should call the function this way:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'posts',
  'limit' => 5,
  'cat' => 'news'
);

function get_posts($args)
{

    $post_type = $args['post_type'];
    $limit = $args['limit'];
    $cat = $args['cat'];

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posttype='$post_type' ..........");
    // ... other code
}

get_posts($args);
```

If you get some errors, please update your question with error log.

Comment: The error was giving cause i have an error in my code... the function was wrote in wrong way....

Comment: Yeah, I get it! Post error message, please (and maybe the full code of `get_posts()` function).